# Sending data between UpdatePanels with ModalPopupExtender in second Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

My overall issue is being able to use a ModalPopupExtender to show the results of data in one UpdatePanel in a second UpdatePanel.

To develop what I want to do I am using the example of using two UpdatePanels shown on the website http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

I have set this up and it works perfectly.

Now I add the complexity of the ModalPopupExtender.

I had difficulties with showing the UpdatePanel using Button1_ModalPopupExtender.Show() and so I needed to understand the whole process.

It seems that ModalPopupExtender "shows" on the OnClientClick event and not the onClick event. This limits the ability to pass data between the UpdatePanels.

To overcome this, I set the TargetControlID to a blank label and set the onClick event for Button1 to Button1_Click.

In Button1_Click I set the values of the Labels in the two UpdatePanels and then could not get the Popup to appear.

Through many online searches I found that I could fire a JavaScript from the Button1_Click event. I setup a javascript function called showpopup() and in the Button1_Click I added a call to this, and this almost does the job.

My Markup is as follows:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.vb" Inherits="CRMDash2.WebForm3" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
    <%@ OutputCache Location="None" NoStore="true" %>

    <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">  
          <script type="text/javascript">
               function showmodalpopup() {

               // see comments below for the impact of various entries here

              return false;
              }
           </script>     
    <article>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="update both" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBlank" runat="server" Text="a" ></asp:Label>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
                    ID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" 
                    runat="server" 
                    PopupControlID="Panel1"
                    CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalbackground"
                    BehaviorID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" 
                    TargetControlID="lblBlank">
                     </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="update this" onClick="Button2_Click"/>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="red" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                     </asp:Panel>

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </div>
        </article>
    </asp:Content>
```

Now my Code Behind is currently:

```
Public Class WebForm3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "showmodalpopup();", True)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString

    End Sub
End Class
```

To the Script

If I simply place the following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
               function showmodalpopup() {
                  alert("Hi!");
                return false;
            }
    </script>
```

The ModalPopup appears and I get a message box saying "Hi!

If I physically click on the lblBlank on the page the popup opens.

If I try and fire a click the lblBlank label ( to fire the modalpopup) using

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function showmodalpopup() {
              document.getElementById("lblBlank").click();
               //alert("Hi!");
            return false;
        }
      </script>
```

I receive an error  0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'click' of undefined or null reference

I have tried a multitude of different suggestions from the web and I get the undefined or null reference all the time.

when I use alert(this.name); I get a blank returned.

How can I fire a click event on the label so that my popup shows?
Is there something wrong with the ScriptManager.RegisterScript line? 
I cannot seems to put my finger on the solution.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ClientIDMode on the label.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblBlank" runat="server" Text="a" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks Travis but I still get 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'click' of undefined or null reference when I try      var l = document.getElementById('lblBlank');
                        l.click();

Comment: Hi Travis, I just tried again and it works, I had a typo in the javascript. Thanks so much for your prompt attention, I appreciate your help